# Editar WooCommerce Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Necesito en el shopping cart de Woocommerce modificar la estructura de la visualización del contenido total (es decir, lo típico del carrito, donde verificas que tengas todo lo que has añadido o eliminas si añadiste algo mas sin querer). La página final esa tengo que modificarla. Creo (no estoy segura) que por lo que he buscado eso está en el archivo de woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php  pero tengo un problema cuando intento acceder a la plantilla y es que me sale un pantallazo en blanco. Por la estructura de Woocommerce y Wordpress, se que hay que utilizar al menos parte de código php.

Entonces, me gustaría saber si es ese archivo o no o cual es exactamente, para empezar a modificar la plantilla (o ver la programación para empezar a ello) y si es ese archivo, también como acceder a él desde wordpress sin un pantallazo blanco (en el peor de los casos me lo descargo y lo edito en mi pc en un notepad++ o similares, pero me gustaría arreglar eso que no se porque se da).

P.D: Pregunté en el wordpress.stackexchange y me dijeron que preguntase en otro stack porque eso no era competencia de ellos (o algo así, mi inglés no es gran cosa).

Comment: ¿qué es la carta de wordpress?

Comment: Hola @Shaz :) Pues la carta de Woocommerce es justo eso, donde sale el resumen etc de lo que has pedido. Esta zona: http://i.imgur.com/TokYRIC.png  Lo de carta es una traducción que hice yo, en inglés siempre es Cart y siempre lo he asociado con carta (como la de los restaurantes etc)

Comment: En ese orden de ideas te sugiero que utilices un nombre genérico para tu "carta" que todos podamos entender, para quienes busquen esta pregunta en el futuro.

Comment: Vale @Shaz, ya puse en el título lo de WooCommerce Cart (así en inglés seguro que no es un nombre erróneo).

Answer (score 4):

El carrito de Woocommerce (Woocommerce Cart como mencionas) está de hecho compuesto por varios archivos. Me acuerdo que hace no mucho tiempo tuve que re-estructurarlo y agregarle/quitarle diferentes secciones. Los archivos relacionados los puedes encontrar en la siguiente carpeta:

```
/templates/cart
```

Modificando cualquiera de esos archivos, podrás personalizar la forma en que se ve el carrito de Woocommerce.

PD: No modifiques directamente los archivos base de Woocommerce, pues si se actualiza Woocommerce vas a perder los cambios (a demás de no ser recomendado editar directamente un plugin). Te recomiendo crear un Child Theme y poner ahí los archivos modificados (o sobre-escribir las plantillas mediante un plugin personalizado). Una práctica bastante usada, si es que ya tienes un tema activo y no quieres crear un Child Theme, es crear una carpeta **woocommerce** dentro del tema actual y poner los archivos modificados ahí, siguiendo la misma estructura que la del plugin (es probable que ya tengas aquella carpeta en el tema actual que utilizas, si es que este es compatible con Woocommerce).

Puedes ver un pequeño artículo que justo habla sobre eso:

http://blog.aulaformativa.com/consultorio-desarrollo-web/

Comment: si, tengo ya un child-theme creado (por razones obvias como las actualizaciones). Entonces lo que me interesa sobretodo saber es la ruta exacta de los archivos que sobreescribirán lo que viene por defecto en woocommerce para que aún con actualizaciones no cambie. ¿La ruta sería wp-content/themes/theme-child? Y ahí crear una carpeta woocommerce y poner los archivos... ¿o podría dejarlos en el mismo sitio, junto con el functions.php etc?

Tengo que editar mas plantillas (no todas de woocommerce, si de otros plugin) y me interesa en especial saber donde deberán de ir esos archivos modificados.

Comment: Si tienes un child-theme en efecto esa sería la ruta. Es decir, crear una carpeta "woocommerce" dentro del child-theme. De hecho si revisas temas integrados con woocommerce, vas a encontrar esta carpeta dentro de aquellos temas.

Comment: Tengo woocommerce pero no tenido que tocar aún nada de los archivos... si me fijé que tengo la carpeta de woocommerce en la zona de plugins. Gracias :) Mañana o pasado empezaré a mirar esta parte (han surgido otras cosillas mas urgentes) y aceptaré la respuesta cuando pueda comprobar de que efectivamente es así (no es que lo dude, es que tengo que estar segura).